# Does glyph quality increase a tree's return rate?

Tags: pc, the-void

In "The Void", does the quality of the donor glyph determine the amount of nerva a tree returns?

What besides the amount of color determines how much a tree returns?

Answer (score 2):

I got this answer in another forum: "So long as it is actually recognized as the donor glyph, it doesn't matter how well or poorly you draw it." http://forum.ice-pick.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=10216&p=110173#p110173